# Is the equation $x^2=x \sin x+ \cos x$ true?

Tags: real-analysis

I came across a problem that says: The equation $x^2=x \sin x+ \cos x$ is true for:

> $1.$No real value of $x$
>   $2.$Exactly one  real value of $x$
>   $3.$Exactly two real values of $x$
>   $4.$Infinitely many real values of $x$  .

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You've only shown that $x=0$ is not a solution to the equation, which you could have done without dividing - and note that $\lim_{x\to\0} \frac{\cos x}{x}$ is infinity, not 1!

Comment: sorry for the silly mistake.I am deleting it.

Comment: A hint: what is the value of $x^2-(x\sin x+\cos x)$ at $x=0$?  What is its value at $x=\pi$?  You should be able to show that there can be no solutions for $x\gt \pi$, and then by computing the derivative figure out how many solutions there are for $0\lt x\lt\pi$.  You'll need to consider the case $x\lt0$ as well, but that should be straightforward.

Comment: Just because $f(x)=g(x)$ is false as $x\to0$ (and it is false in your case, though your reasoning as to why it is false is invalid as the other comment says), does not mean that $f(x)=g(x)$ is never possible for any values of $x$.

Comment: You are right. It was a silly conclusion to make.

Comment: Funnily enough, $\mathrm{i}\sin\mathrm{i} + \cos\mathrm{i} = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \cdot \mathrm{i}} = (\mathrm{i})^2(-1/\mathrm{e})$. Missed it by a factor of $(-1/\mathrm{e})$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$f(x) = x^2-x \sin x- \cos x$.

$f(0) = -1$,
$f(\pi/2) = \pi^2/4 - \pi/2 > 0$,
and
$f(-\pi/2) = f(\pi/2) > 0$,
so $f$ has at least two real roots.

$f(-x) = f(x)$
(since $f(-x) = (-x)^2 - (-x)\sin(-x) - \cos(-x)
= x^2 - x \sin(x) - \cos(x) = f(x)$,
 so we only need look at $x > 0$.

Since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are bounded by $1$,
$f(x) > x^2 - x - 1
> 0$
for $x > 2$ certainly
(you can get the actual root, but we only need a bound).

The only way that case (4) can hold
is if $f$ has an infinite number of roots
in a finite region
(like $\sin(1/x)$
in $(0, 1)$).
However this cannot hold
since $f'(x)$ is bounded.

So the answer seems to be (3).